# Updating Firestore document with typescript map array type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've created a map data type in Typescript react
Example:

```
let employees = new Map<string, string>();
employees.set("name", "john");
```

and this is how I'm adding new values to firestore

```
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("initialQuestions")
ref.doc('abc').set({ ??? })
```

The above method works only for a single value, how do I push the whole map at once to firestore?

Answer (score 0):

Working with the JS web SDK, pure Javascript Objects are the only accepted type of data. This is shown in the SDK [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#adddoc) and the error message you would get by passing directly any other custom object that isn’t a pure JS object:

> “Error [FirebaseError]: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Data must be an object, but it was: a custom Map object (found in document users/testUser1)”

Something the Firebase SDK makes available for this purpose is the [`FirestoreDataCoverter`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.firestoredataconverter) interface. This interface lets you create custom conversions from any data Class to a pure JS object. I created and tested the below code to convert a Map of Strings into Objects.

```ts
const firestoreDB = firebase.firestore();

let myMap = new Map<String, String>();
myMap.set("firstName", "Foo");
myMap.set("lastName", "Bar");

var mapConverter = {
  toFirestore: function(mapObj: Map<String, String>) { //toFirestore builds an Object which is returned and uploaded to Firestore
      return {
          firstName: mapObj.get("firstName"),
          lastName: mapObj.get("lastName"),
          };
  },
  fromFirestore: function(snapshot, options){ //fromFirestore is used to convert Objects fetched from Firestore to your custom Types
      const data = snapshot.data(options);
      return new Map<String, String>(Object.entries(data));
  }
};

firestoreDB.collection("users").doc("testUser1").withConverter(mapConverter).set(myMap) //using the converter, myMap can be passed directly
.then(() => {
  console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

For your specific use case, the `toFirestore()` function will take your complete Map object and return a JS Object. Note that when I set my document, I append the `withConverter(mapConverter)` function. This function takes my converter implementation and uses it with the object I pass to the `set()` method, and no error is thrown by the SDK.

A simpler approach than this would be to use the [`Object.fromEntries(myMap)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) built-in function. This function would simply map everything into an Object. It worked on my tests, but it doesn’t offer much customization as a `FirestoreDataConverter` does.

```ts
const firestoreDB = firebase.firestore();

let myMap = new Map<String, String>();
myMap.set("firstName", "Foo");
myMap.set("lastName", "Bars");

firestoreDB.collection("users").doc("testUser1").set(Object.fromEntries(myMap))
.then(() => {
  console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

Comment: @SumukhJadhav I edited my answer to make it more clear. Do you still need any help with this question?

Comment: @SumukhJadhav In case you also needed for the existing fields in your documents to not be always overwritten, the `merge: true` property can be passed to the `set()` method in a second parameter like so: `firestoreDB.collection("users").withConverter(mapConverter).doc("testUser1").set(myMap, {merge: true})`. I tested it and this works in both of the methods included in my answer.